# Adding lines to multiple Notes.ini files

Tags: powershell, ini

I have a PowerShell script that I want to run to add two lines 'IM_DISABLED' & 'IM_NO_SETUP=1' to the end of each INI file.

I want to run it against a folder `H:\test` which has subfolders each containing a file `notes.ini`.

I have the following PowerShell which works using `-replace`. However, I'm unable to use replace and need to just append two new lines to the end of each INI.

```
$places = 'h:\test'
$places | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include Notes.ini | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_) -replace 'KitType=1', "`nKitType=1`r`nIM_DISABLED=1`r`nIM_NO_SETUP=1" |
        Set-Content $_
    'Processed: {0}' -f $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can simply use `Add-Content`:

```
$places = 'h:\test'
$lines  = 'IM_DISABLED', 'IM_NO_SETUP=1'
Get-ChildItem $places -Recurse -Include Notes.ini | ForEach-Object {
  Add-Content $_.FullName -Value $lines
  'Processed: {0}' -f $_.FullName
}
```

On earlier versions you can use `Out-File` with the parameter `-Append`. Note that you also need to define the encoding if the file isn't Unicode-encoded.

```
$places = 'h:\test'
$lines  = 'IM_DISABLED', 'IM_NO_SETUP=1'
Get-ChildItem $places -Recurse -Include Notes.ini | ForEach-Object {
  Out-File $_.FullName -InputObject $lines -Append -Encoding Ascii
  'Processed: {0}' -f $_.FullName
}
```

Another option is to make an array of `Get-Content` output and the lines you want to add and write that back to the file with `Set-Content`:

```
$places = 'h:\test'
Get-ChildItem $places -Recurse -Include Notes.ini | ForEach-Object {
  $f = $_.FullName
  (Get-Content $f), 'IM_DISABLED', 'IM_NO_SETUP=1' | Set-Content $f
  'Processed: {0}' -f $f
}
```